# Android emulator not working because of an internal error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting an error on the emulator when I try to run the app on android studio, the error is:

```
Android Emulator closed because of an internal error: Detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 15000 ms
```

I have no idea what's causing this error, everything was working fine before.

Please help!

Comment: @statosdotcom I've looked at that thread before creating this one, but it hasn't been helpful. I'm now facing the struggling of getting the virtuak machine to come online

Comment: Delete the virtual device and create the new one. See if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cold boot the the virtual device that's causing the problem. To do so, open Tools -> Android -> AVD manager. When it opens, click on the rightmost black arrow for the device in question and choose "Cold Boot Now" option. This will restart your virtual device and hopefully your problem will go away.

A clip from documentation:

> Beginining with revision 27.0.2, the Android Emulator includes Quick Boot, which launches the emulator in just a few seconds. Although the AVD must perform a cold boot the first time you start it (just like powering on a device), all subsequent starts use Quick Boot—it boots fast and the system is restored to the state at which you closed the emulator or manually saved a snapshot (similar to waking a device). This feature is enabled by default for all AVDs.

Comment: Hi, This option doesn't exist. Is "Wipe Data" equivalent to Cold Boot? I've tried wiping the data but that hasn't helped.

Comment: It is a new option introduced in one of the last updates. I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and this option is present. What you can also try regardless of the Studio version is deleting the virtual device and creating a new one. See if that solves the problem.